# Scala, get sum of multidimensional array

Tags: scala, spark-graphx

By using trianglecount from GraphX, I retrieve the following array:

```
Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Int)] = Array((1,1), (3,1), (2,1))
```

I'm trying to find a way to sum the second value of each element in the array. Thus the 1's in this example.

I haven't been able to find a method how to do this.

Comment: You'll do much better if you make an attempt and post what you have.  No one can tell if you don't know Scala or are just too lazy from this question.

Comment: Understood. Had been busy with this for quite a while some days ago, so couldn't remember what I'd tried. Definitely get your point. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scala> val res = Array((1,1), (3,1), (2,1))
res: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,1), (3,1), (2,1))

scala> res.map(_._2).sum
res7: Int = 3
```

or in one operation:

```
scala> res.foldLeft(0){case (acc, (k,v)) => acc +v }
res8: Int = 3
```